# how to update null rows in join table

Tags: mysql, database, swing, sql-insert

I have 2 tables: sellers with fields(seller_id  name) and movies with field(movie_id , name , genre). It two tables has "many-to many" relationship , so also I have third  join table "sellers_movies" with fields seller_id | movie_id. It fields has null value in the start. So my problem is: for example we add movie_id in "movies" table , and is it possible automatically update field movie_id in table "sellers_movies" from null to what we wrote in "movies" table ??

Comment: you don't can update rows that not exist .. you must insert the rows for relation

Comment: @scaisEdge but what about   LAST_INSERT_ID() ? It doesn't help?

Comment: to me seems not related to your question .. .. there si a deep difference between a row that exist , then with almost one field different form null and a row that not exists.   Your relation table seller:movies must be fullfilled by insert  .. (and eventually update if the single relation change) for mantein the proper relation between the two table .. the last_insert_id ..what mean for this .?.

Comment: @scaisEdge here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html i read  "If you want to use the ID that was generated for one table and insert it into a second table, you can use SQL statements like this:"  So if i understand I must to fill this join table, yes?? But you say: "and eventually update if the single relation change" ,  i don't undertand ,  for example seller_id = 1 | movie_id   = 2 ,   seller_id = 2 | movie_id   = 3 , i develop it on java swing and for example  i  change movie_id to 20  from form textfield , how database detects  that i change movie_id = 3?

Comment: Hi there, your question is not clear as it is right now. You say you want to update the `sellers_movies` table with the ID inserted. You can only UPDATE (pay attention to that word) existent rows. Say you just inserted on the movies table (1 - Matrix) so, since `sellers_movies` table is a relationship table, many-to-many, I THINK that you mean is to create a relation between all sellers with the ID just inserted, so if the seller has 1-Bla and 2-Ble, you want to INSERT 1, 1 and 1, 2 not update. Did I understand it right? If so, let me know. I can prepare an answer to you.

Comment: Please edit relevant code into your question.

Comment: @JorgeCampos  , hello  , yes i want to create a relation between all sellers with the ID just inserted

Comment: If every seller appears with every ID then sellers_movies is redundant.

Comment: @philipxy Would you explain why, please? Without the relationship table you would have to control this on the application code, AFAIK, right?

Comment: @JorgeCampos All my last comment says is that if every seller sells every movie (which M-Misha-Mseem seems to have said but which seems unlikely to be what they want) then sellers_movies is just a projection of a join of sellers & movies. I agree with your comments, especially that *the question is not clear*.

Comment: Your question and comments are not clear. Please tell us exactly what the input is, including parameters, and what language(s) you are writing in. Eg there should be no nulls in sellers_movies. Eg what is "it" in "it's fields have null values at the start"? Please also show some example code.

Answer (score 0):

You would be good with a `trigger` on your table `movies`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER associateMoviesToSellers
 BEFORE INSERT ON movies
 FOR EACH ROW
 BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sellers_movies (seller_id, movie_id)
       SELECT s.seller_id, NEW.movie_id 
         FROM sellers s;
 END;
```

Then for every row inserted on `movies` it will create an association for every seller on `sellers_movies` table.